# Зачем поменяли стили цитат?

Tags: поддержка, редактор

> Добавьте всю информацию, которая может понадобиться для ответа на ваш вопрос

Раньше цитаты как-то сильнее выделялись от авторского текста, сейчас совсем немного. В чём смысл изменений?

Comment: Тот же вопрос — зачем?

Answer (score 5):

На MSE тоже многие жаловались.

Инициатива по изменению отображению цитат [была предложена ~20 дней назад](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919/260198). Там же можно почитать и о причинах. К примеру, одна из причин - отделить цитаты от спойлеров.

Comment: да кому вообще нужны эти не колапсируемые спойлеры?

Comment: @4per у дизайнеров SE особый взгляд на вещи. Мне многие их решения по UX/UI тоже не по душе.