# Нравится ли вам новый стиль цитат?

Tags: обсуждение, дизайн, голосование

Нравится ли вам новый стиль цитат?

> a quote

Comment: Связанное: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10227/339283

Comment: А в чём, собственно, вопрос? Зачем это голосование? Не думаю, что мы сможем повлиять на политику дизайнеров SE.

Comment: @nomnoms Вот если выяснится, что много недовольных, то пойдем на MSE и будем добиваться отката ...

Comment: @nomnoms12, ну а вдруг?

Comment: Старый фон определённо был слишком яркий. Новый фон определённо слишком неяркий. Вот подложить что-нибудь очень-светло-серое наверное было бы неплохо (на глазок что-то вроде #f5f5f5, а может и #f8f8f8, но на разных мониторах проверить надо)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Нет

Нет, раньше было лучше, да и привычней как-то ...

Ещё и скриншоты снова сливаются. Специально же их в цитаты клали, чтобы другой фон был, а теперь всё как до этого :(

Comment: Я лично считаю так...

Answer (score -1):

## Да

Да, новый стиль читать лучше чем раньше.

Answer (score -1):

Мне, лично, нравится. Только бы серый фон за текстом добавить

Comment: Да вы другой-то и не видели...

Comment: Учитывая что они по сути отсутствием фона и отличаются, какое-то это сомнительное "да". Не против, если я его уберу из ответа?

Comment: @Qwertiy Может навесишь [tag:важное]?А когда голосование кончится, то заблокируем, а результаты покажет на MSE.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, мы посовещались и решили не вешать.